# Adding multiple additional columns using Yii2 Migration

Tags: php, yii2

Just wondering what the best way is to add new columns via a migration in yii2. The documentation seems to imply when adding additional columns you should do them one per migration, well at least in the example.
[Yii2 Migration - Add Column](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-migrations.html#add-column). Is this the case, or is it OK to add multiple ADDITIONAL columns in a single migration? If so would you use a specific migration naming convention like `add_xxx_and_zzz_column_to_yyy_table`. Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It isn't clear from the docs but you can create multiple columns in one migration:

```
yii migrate/create add_xxx_column_yyy_column_to_zzz_table --fields="xxx:integer,yyy:text"
```

Comment: Tested and worked as you described and as I was after. Thanks!